# Javascript for table and lookup table

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-events, lookup-tables

I'm trying to make a website that has a table containing a Chinese character in each cell. The user clicks on individual cells, and the character in each cell is displayed in a text-box next to the table. The sequence of characters is found in a lookup table, and an English translation is provided in a second text box.
Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <head>
    <title>
        Practice translation
    </title>
    <script 
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="Small1.js">
    </script>                                                       
    <meta 
        http-equiv="Content-Type" 
        content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link 
        rel="shortcut icon" 
        href="/favicon.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon">    
    <link 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" 
        href="Small1.css">
    <link 
        rel="shortcut icon" 
        href="Pallindrome.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon">
    <link 
        rel="icon" 
        href="Pallindrome.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon">
</head>
</head>
<body>  
    <table  style="text-align:center">
        <tbody> 
    <tr>                    
        <td id= “M13” style="text-align:center" title="“duān“ end, extreme; head; beginning" class="yellow">端</td>
        <td id= “N13” style="text-align:center" title="“wú, mó“ negative, no, not; KangXi radical 71" class="yellow">无</td>
        <td id= “O13” style="text-align:center" title="“zhōng“ end; finally, in the end" color="#f1c232" class="yellow">终</td>
        <td id= “P13” style="text-align:center" title="“shǐ“ begin, start; then, only then" class="yellow">始</td>
        <td id= “Q13” style="text-align:center" title="“shī“ poetry; poem, verse, ode"class="yellow">诗</td>
       
    </tr>                   
    <tr>                    
        
        <td id= “M14” style="text-align:center" title="“bǐ, bì, pí, pǐ“ to compare, liken; comparison; than" class="yellow">比</td>
        <td id= “N14” style="text-align:center" title="“píng“ flat, level, even; peaceful" class="green" >平</td>
        <td id= “O14” style="text-align:center" title="“shǐ“ begin, start; then, only then" class="green">始</td>
        <td id= “P14” style="text-align:center" title="“xuán“ beautiful jade; star" class="green">璇</td>
        <td id= “Q14” style="text-align:center" title="“qíng“ feeling, sentiment, emotion" class="yellow">情</td>  
        
    </tr>                   
    <tr>
                        
        <td id= “M15” style="text-align:center" title="“zuò, zuō, zuó“ make; work; compose, write; act, perform" class="yellow">作</td>
        <td id= “N15” style="text-align:center" title="“sū“ revive, resurrect; a species of thyme" class="green">苏</td>
        <td id= “O15” style="text-align:center" title="“xīn“ heart; mind, intelligence; soul" class="red" >心</td>
        <td id= “P15” style="text-align:center" title="“jī“ pearl that is not quite round" class="green">玑</td>
        <td id= “Q15” style="text-align:center" title="“míng“ bright, light, brilliant; clear" class="yellow">明</td>
              
    </tr>                   
    <tr>                    
       
        <td id= “M16” style="text-align:center" title="“lì, lí“ beautiful, magnificent, elegant" class="yellow">丽</td>
        <td id= “N16” style="text-align:center" title="“shì, zhī, jīng“ clan, family; mister" class="green">氏</             td>
        <td id= “O16” style="text-align:center" title="“shī“ poetry; poem, verse, ode"  class="green">诗</td>
        <td id= “P16” style="text-align:center" title="“tú“ diagram; chart, map, picture" class="green" >图</td>
        <td id= “Q16” style="text-align:center" title="“xiǎn“ manifest, display; evident, clear" class="yellow" >显          </td>
    </tr>                   
    <tr>
        <td id= “M17” style="text-align:center" title="“cí“ words, speech, expression, phrase" class="yellow" >辞</          td>
        <td id= “N17” style="text-align:center" title="“lǐ“ reason, logic; manage" class="yellow" >理</td>
        <td id= “O17” style="text-align:center" title="“xīng, xìng“ thrive, prosper, flourish" class="yellow" >兴</          td>
        <td id= “P17” style="text-align:center" title="“yì“ right conduct, righteousness" class="yellow" >义</td>
        <td id= “Q17” style="text-align:center" title="“yuàn“ hatred, enmity, resentment" class="yellow" >怨</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
type="text/css">                                                                                            
.table  
    {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-spacing:0;
    }                                                                               
.table  td
    {
        font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size:19px;
        padding:10px 5px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        overflow:hidden;
        word-break:normal;
    }
.table  
    .red    {color:#fe0000}                                                                                             
    .green  {color:#32cb00}                                                                                         
    .yellow {color:#ffc702}
```

The JAVAScript lookup table I have is:

```
var lookupTable = {
    "端无终始诗":"The beginning of this poem starts at the end,",
    "比平始璇情":"It begins peacefully like a smooth jade star",
    "作苏心玑明":"Its creation revived my twisted heart",
    "丽氏诗图显":"Clearly this star-chart poem is a classic",
    "辞理兴义怨":"Knowledge thrives where good calls out evil",
    "端比作丽辞":"The beginning of this work is like a great speech"};
```

(note that not all click-combinations will produce an English translation).

What I'm having trouble with is:

1. Creating an event listener that will detect clicks and send the cell
   contents to the Chinese text box
2. Looking up the text in the Chinese box with the lookup table and
3. Displaying the results in the English translation box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Especially written code!

Comment: `$(".classOfTheCell").on("click",function(){//code here});` - This is event delegation ! you can use this !

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple elements for the results:

```
<div id=output></div>
<div id=translation></div>
```

Then this code will process the clicks and produce the results:

```
function processClick(event) {
   var elem = $('#output');
   elem.text(elem.text() + $(event.target).text());
   $('#translation').text(lookupTable[elem.text()]);
   }
$(document).on('click', 'td', processClick);
```

Fiddle with the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6wjeuymj/1/

Note that a wrapper around the table (and results elements) with a class name (example: `<div class=translator-puzzle>`...`</div>`) would enable you to write cleaner (and safer) code by effectively making a reusable component relying on classes instead of ids.